# Hide navigation header if its empty

Tags: html, razor, umbraco

I would like to hide the header and footer of my side navigation if it contains no values.

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage

<div id="LeftMenuHolder">               @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    <span class="Head-Round-Red">       @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
        <span>@CurrentPage.Name</span>  @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    </span>@*<----Not show these if list is empty*@

    <ul>
        @if (CurrentPage.Parent.DocumentTypeAlias == "Home")
        {
            foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible"))
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@item.Url">
                        <span>@item.Name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var sibling in CurrentPage.Parent.Children)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@sibling.Url">
                        <span>@sibling.Name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
    <span class="BoxBot">      @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
        <span></span>          @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    </span>                    @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    </div>
```

I'm sure this can be solved with an if-statement, but im not quite sure.

Comment: Does your side navigation include pages that are "sibling" (in the same structure level) nodes to the current page? Or is it a different kind of implementation?

Comment: @MarkoJ.I does include the the pages that are siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this for retrieving the sibling nodes and afterwards checking if the list is empty:

```
IPublishedContent parentNode = Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Parent;

IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> siblingNodes = Umbraco.
                                              AssignedContentItem.
                                              Parent.
                                              Children.
                                              Where(x => !x.Name.Equals(Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Name) &&
                                                         ((bool)x.GetProperty("UmbracoNaviHide") == false);
```

For your implementation, try something like this with the initialized properties (if you don't have `UmbracoNaviHide` in the page, remove it from `Linq` statement) and also remove this condition if you want to display the current page item: `Where(x => !x.Name.Equals(Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Name)`

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>

@{
     IPublishedContent parentNode = Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Parent;

     IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> siblingNodes = Umbraco.
                                                   AssignedContentItem.
                                                   Parent.
                                                   Children.
                                                   Where(x => !x.Name.Equals(Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Name) &&
                                                              ((bool)x.GetProperty("UmbracoNaviHide") == false);
}

@if(siblingNodes.Any())
{
<div id="LeftMenuHolder">               @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    <span class="Head-Round-Red">       @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
        <span>@CurrentPage.Name</span>  @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    </span>                             @*<----Not show these if list is empty*@
}

    <ul>
        @if (CurrentPage.Parent.DocumentTypeAlias == "Home")
        {
            foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible"))
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@item.Url">
                        <span>@item.Name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var sibling in CurrentPage.Parent.Children)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@sibling.Url">
                        <span>@sibling.Name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
@if(siblingNodes.Any())
{
    <span class="BoxBot">      @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
        <span></span>          @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
    </span>                    @*<----Not show/include these if list is empty*@
}
    </div>
```

Also, the `Umbraco` variable is available from `UmbracoViewPage`, so you will have to change your inherits model to something like this: `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>`.